# Arrays not properly sorting

Tags: java, eclipse

Good afternoon. I have created an application for an introductory java course that allows a user to sort their DVD collection by title, studio, or year. The application also allows the user to add additional DVD's to their collection, thus enlarging their arrays. The code properly compiles, but there is clearly something wrong as the titles, studio, and years are mixing themselves up. To be clear, this code is from a textbook and is part of a lab that requires the use of the exact methods, packages, etc. that you see in the code. I'm not asking for advice on how to make the code more efficient (although that is welcome as I am learning), but specifically what is wrong with the code provided causing the "scramble". Here is the code I have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class DVD extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    // construct components
    JLabel sortPrompt = new JLabel("Sort by:");
    JComboBox fieldCombo = new JComboBox();
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

    // initialize data in arrays
    String title[] = {"Casablanca", "Citizen Kane", "Singin' in the Rain", "The Wizard of Oz"};
    String studio[] = {"Warner Brothers", "RKO Pictures", "MGM", "MGM"};
    String year[] = {"1942", "1941", "1952", "1939"};

    // construct instance of DVD
    public DVD()
    {
        super("Classics on DVD");
    }

    // create the menu system
    public JMenuBar createMenuBar()
    {
        // create an instance of the menu
        JMenuBar mnuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(mnuBar);

        // construct and populate the File menu
        JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File", true);
            mnuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            mnuFile.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            mnuBar.add(mnuFile);

        JMenuItem mnuFileExit = new JMenu("Exit");
            mnuFileExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
            mnuFileExit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
            mnuFile.add(mnuFileExit);
            mnuFileExit.setActionCommand("Exit");
            mnuFileExit.addActionListener(this);

        // contruct and populate the Edit menu
        JMenu mnuEdit = new JMenu("Edit", true);
            mnuEdit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            mnuEdit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            mnuBar.add(mnuEdit);

        JMenuItem mnuEditInsert = new JMenuItem("Insert New DVD");
            mnuEditInsert.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            mnuEditInsert.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            mnuEdit.add(mnuEditInsert);
            mnuEditInsert.setActionCommand("Insert");
            mnuEditInsert.addActionListener(this);

        JMenu mnuEditSearch = new JMenu("Search");
            mnuEditSearch.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            mnuEditSearch.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
            mnuEdit.add(mnuEditSearch);

        JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByTitle = new JMenuItem("by Title");
            mnuEditSearchByTitle.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            mnuEditSearchByTitle.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
            mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByTitle);
            mnuEditSearchByTitle.setActionCommand("title");
            mnuEditSearchByTitle.addActionListener(this);

        JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByStudio = new JMenuItem("by Studio");
            mnuEditSearchByStudio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            mnuEditSearchByStudio.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
            mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByStudio);
            mnuEditSearchByStudio.setActionCommand("studio");
            mnuEditSearchByStudio.addActionListener(this);

        JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByYear = new JMenuItem("by Year");
            mnuEditSearchByYear.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
            mnuEditSearchByYear.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
            mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByYear);
            mnuEditSearchByYear.setActionCommand("year");
            mnuEditSearchByYear.addActionListener(this);

        return mnuBar;
    }

    // create the content pane
    public Container createContentPane()
    {
        // populate the JComboBox
        fieldCombo.addItem("Title");
        fieldCombo.addItem("Studio");
        fieldCombo.addItem("Year");
        fieldCombo.addActionListener(this);
        fieldCombo.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arrow to display sort fields.");

        // construct and populate the north panel
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
            northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            northPanel.add(sortPrompt);
            northPanel.add(fieldCombo);

        // create the JTextPane and center panel
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
            setTabsAndStyles(textPane);
            textPane = addTextToTextPane();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

        // create Container and set attributes
        Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
            c.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            c.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return c;
    }

    // method to create tab stops and set font styles
    protected void setTabsAndStyles(JTextPane textPane)
    {
        // create Tab Stops
        TabStop[] tabs = new TabStop[2];
            tabs[0] = new TabStop(200, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
            tabs[1] = new TabStop(350, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
        TabSet tabset = new TabSet(tabs);

        // set Tab Style
        StyleContext tabStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset =
            tabStyle.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet, tabset);
        textPane.setParagraphAttributes(aset, false);

        // set Font styles
        Style fontStyle =
            StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

        Style regular = textPane.addStyle("regular", fontStyle);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(fontStyle, "SansSerif");

        Style s = textPane.addStyle("italic", regular);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(s, true);

        s = textPane.addStyle("bold", regular);
        StyleConstants.setBold(s, true);

        s = textPane.addStyle("large", regular);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(s, 16);
    }

    // method to add new text to the JTextPane
    public JTextPane addTextToTextPane()
    {
        Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
        try
        {
            // clear the previous text
            doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());

            // insert title
            doc.insertString(0,"TITLE\tSTUDIO\tYEAR\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

            // insert detail
            for (int j = 0; j<title.length; j++)
            {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), title[j] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("bold"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), studio[j] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("italic"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), year[j] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
            }
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't insert text.");
        }

        return textPane;
    }

    // event to process user clicks
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String arg = e.getActionCommand();

        // user clicks the sort by combo box
        if (e.getSource() == fieldCombo)
        {
            switch(fieldCombo.getSelectedIndex())
            {
                case 0:
                    sort(title);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sort(studio);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sort(year);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // user clicks Exit on the File menu
        if (arg == "Exit")
            System.exit(0);

        // user clicks Insert New DVD on the Edit Menu
        if (arg == "Insert")
        {
            // accept new data
            String newTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the new movie's title");
            String newStudio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the studio for " + newTitle);
            String newYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the year for " + newTitle);

            // enlarge arrays
            title = enlargeArray(title);
            studio = enlargeArray(studio);
            year = enlargeArray(year);

            // add new data to arrays
            title[title.length-1] = newTitle;
            studio[studio.length-1] = newStudio;
            year[year.length-1] = newYear;

            // call sort method
            sort(title);
            fieldCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }

        // user clicks Title on the Search submenu
        if (arg == "title")
            search(arg, title);

        // user clicks Studio on the Search submenu
        if (arg == "studio")
            search(arg, studio);

        // user clicks Year on the Search submenu
        if (arg == "year")
            search(arg, year);
    }

    // method to enlarge an array by 1
    public String[] enlargeArray(String[] currentArray)
    {
        String[] newArray = new String[currentArray.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i<currentArray.length; i++)
            newArray[i] = currentArray[i];
        return newArray;
    }

    // method to sort arrays
    public void sort(String tempArray[])
    {
        // loop ton control number of passes
        for (int pass = 1; pass < tempArray.length; pass++)
        {
            for (int element = 0; element < tempArray.length - 1; element++)
                if (tempArray[element].compareTo(tempArray[element + 1])>0)
                {
                    swap(title, element, element + 1);
                    swap(studio, element, element + 1);
                    swap(year, element, element + 1);
                }
        }
        addTextToTextPane();
    }

    // method to swap two elements of an array
    public void swap(String swapArray[], int first, int second)
    {
        String hold; // temporary holding area for swap
        hold = swapArray[first];
        swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
        swapArray[second] = hold;
    }

    public void search(String searchField, String searchArray[])
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = textPane.getDocument(); // assign text to document object
            doc.remove(0,doc.getLength()); // clear previous text

            // display column titles
            doc.insertString(0,"TITLE\tSTUDIO\tYEAR\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

            // prompt user for search data
            String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the "+searchField);
            boolean found = false;

            // search arrays
            for (int i = 0; i<title.length; i++)
            {
                if (search.compareTo(searchArray[i])==0)
                {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), title[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("bold"));
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), studio[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("italic"));
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), year[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (found == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your search produced no results.","No results found",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                sort(title);
            }
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't insert text.");
        }
    }

    // main method executes at run time
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        DVD f = new DVD();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setJMenuBar(f.createMenuBar());
        f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
        f.setSize(600,375);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot to give you a sense of what I mean be "scrambled".
[image: Scrambled Application]

Obviously, all of the titles should be in the title column, studios in studio, and years in year.

As always, I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), year[j] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
```

where you put a tab (`"\t"`) after the year but instead you want a newline (`"\n"`). So the line becomes

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), year[j] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Being that I am just starting to learn java, I still make many simple mistakes. Having the help you all on SO provided has been instrumental in my development thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply miss a newline after adding the year of a DVD to the document? I.e.

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), year[j] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
```